# Why does the ArcGIS Sample tool skip rows and points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, esri-grid-format, sample

I'm using **ArcGIS 10.4** and want to **export XYZ** values of a **raster** (type: GRID) to a **text file**. I'm following the procedure recommended by [ESRI support](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000007693). However, it seems that the **Sample Tool** in spatial analyst toolbox skips a bunch of points. When I display the XY-Data certain **rows and points are incorrect**, either 0 or -9999 (not displayed).

[image: Results from sample tool: -9999 not displayed]

I tried this with different input data, and i cannot find an explanation at all. I thought this might be because of the ArcGIS instance i was runnning, but I tried the sample tool in an freshly started ArcCatalog window. *Almost* the same happens there, just that the points are not 100% identically.

[image: Results from sample tool, different instance]

Is this a bug, or am I doing something completely wrong? How do I fix this?

It seems to be related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63702/arcgis-spatial-analyst-sample-returns-null-values?rq=1) from 3 years ago.

Edit: Several new tries (see suggestions below), resulting in different patterns. Could still not find the solution to this problem.
Another screenshot with nearly the same area, different zoom, different color scale. -9999 is bright yellow, 0 is dark color.

[image: same area, different view, different color scale. -9999 is bright yellow, 0 is dark color]

Comment: Does the same problem occur when using (or not using) background geoprocessing?

Comment: I've been using background processing so far. Tested it just now with foreground processing, same error, same line. It seems that ArcGIS skips a line every 30 lines (width at this location is 1200 rows, but this varies).

Comment: What is your processing extent?

Comment: Processing extent is default and corresponds to ETRS89 32N 418600m - 509100m E 5877800m - 6000000m N. Cellsize 25m. Changing this to the raster extent does not work either.

Comment: What happens if you select the points giving an erroneous result and then run the spatial sample on only those points?

Comment: The error is not reproducible any more when i split the raster into several pieces (4). Normally the Sample tool refuses to work when the raster is too big.

Comment: Ignore my previous answer it ist still there. Every 32 Lines there is a break with either -9999 or null values. Still don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem roots in the raster (based on the comments), though the underlying reason for the problem still remains unknown. Try to run raster calculator without any function on your entire raster to produce a new raster and then use the `Sample` tool.

Other useful information on the issue at hand:

As per `Sample` tool documentation:

> Locations that sample NoData cells in the input raster or rasters will
>   be given a  value in an output geodatabase table. For output to
>   INFO or .dbf, since the concept of null is not supported, a value of 0
>   (zero) will be given.

Therefore the zero value may roots in NoData cells.

A few suggestions:

1. Change the raster format to a format other than GRID
2. Make sure the input raster coordinate system and [Output Coordinate System](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-coordinate-system.htm) environment variable are the same, i.e. no coordinate transformation happens
3. Make sure the `Cell Size` environment variable and input raster cell size are in agreement too.

Unfortunately The `Sample` tool is not a python tool, thus the source code could not be seen that on what condition -9999 values are produced!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. There are no NoData cells nearby (next 5km away). The pattern in that particular area is not affected by the NoData cells. 1) I tried the tiff-format, similiar errors, same lines, different pattern (see new screenshot above) 2+3) I tried your suggestions, unfortunately no improvements.

Comment: I am eager to test your clipped raster (for the buggy area) on my 10.2.2 ArcGIS!

Comment: I split the raster into 4 equal parts. The error is not reproducible any more. Is there a limit in raster size for the Sample tool? Quite often I noticed that the sample tool will simply not work, when the raster is too big.

Comment: I doubt it if there is a limit for the raster size. Non is indicated in the doc! Try to run raster calculator without any function on your entire raster to produce a new raster and see if it works. I think there is something wrong with the raster!

Comment: Okay, i used the Raster Calculator, saved the output in the Default.gdb, Sample Tool kept crashing (this info may not be relevant). Used it again, saved the output outside of gdb, Sample Tool took some time, but now it is working! No pattern, all values look reasonable. Can you imaging what was wrong with the raster? It originated from Mosaic to new Raster tool with different cell size input. Please update your answer, then i will mark it as correct. Many thanks!

Comment: When you use raster calculator, it reset all the raster properties to that of the Environmental Variables; i.e. cell size, pixel depth, coordinate system and etc change in the process. My guess goes to cell size. a very small cell size may result in the -9999 values!

Comment: My bad! It still does not work, i used the wrong column to display. When using the Sample tool it will give me 2 Columns with results (rname and rname_1) rname has always values, but INT only. In my previous answer i displayed and referred to this first INT column. The second (rname_1) column shows NULL values every 800m/32 Lines.

Comment: It looks like there might be an issue with the ArcGIS version (10.4) i'm working with. I tested the same dataset on a different computer with 10.4, keeps producing errors. I tested the same dataset on another computer with ArcGIS 10.2, Sample Tool works fine. Same problem has been described here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/175540

Comment: On the basis of your statements it seems this is a bug in 10.4. Contact ESRI support.